# Why is another nested for loop required to to search the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

So the code in question is a very basic scrabble score calculator. It's a challenge on the CodeCademy website.

The **correct** code as defined by them is as follows, as you can see there is a nested for loop which searches the whole dictionary for every letter in *word*:

```
    score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
  word = word.lower()
  total = 0
  for letter in word:
    for leter in score:
      if letter == leter:
        total = total + score[leter]
  return total
```

I'm relatively new to Python, but from what I understand, the for loop should be able to work as below, with it looping through each letter in the *word* variable, using it as the key in the *score* dictionary and consequently adding it to *total*. As you can see it then returns *total*.

```
def scrabble_score(word):
  word = word.lower()
  total = 0
  for letter in word:
    total = total + score[letter]
  return total
```

However, CodeCademy says that is wrong. Could someone kindly explain what I'm missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct and much more optimised, add try/catch block just in case!

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    word = word.lower()
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
      try:
        total += score[letter]
      except KeyError, e:
        print "Error: Letter {} is missing from the score".format(e)
    return total
```

Comment: Cheers Amit, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer doesn't seem to be incorrect. It performs as expected. CodeAcademy's accepted answers are likely prohibitively restrictive in this case.

Comment: Cheers Ben, appreciate the help.